# The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'. in WinForm

Tags: c#

I am building a windows application using C#. In my login form, I'm getting *Select Command property has not been initialized before calling fill method*.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class frmlogin : Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TH07L019;Initial Catalog=loginerror;Integrated Security=True");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();

    public frmlogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from login where username='" + txt1.Text + "' and password='" + txt2.Text +"'";
        adp.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            frmmain main = new frmmain();
            main.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter correct name and passowrd", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to assign the `SqlCommand` object to the `SqlDataAdapter` - just like the error says. :)  And please look into parameterized queries - as you're code is now your ripe for SQL Injection.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to specify select command of SqlDataAdapter before filling your table. You are not doing it. Your SqlCommand object is not connected in any way to your SqlDataAdapter.

```
 adp.SelectCommand=cmd;
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way to accomplish would be to simply pass the SQLCommand as an argument into your data adapter as follows -

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Comment: it is more efficient way to accomplish the job. thanks

Answer (score 0):

SQL Data Adapter interacts with the data table. It is used to fill the Data Table from SQL Server DataBase. Before, filling the Data Table, the Data Adapter should know the command it is going to execute. So we have to fill the object of SQL Command Type i.e

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Here `cmd` is the object of SQL Command.

Now, the Data Adapter will know which command to execute before filling the data table.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Employees_Details_Management_System
{
    public partial class ShowEmpDtlsFrm : Form
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (local); Initial Catalog = sp_emp; Integrated Security = True");

        public SqlCommand cmd { get; private set; }

        // private SqlCommand cmd;

        public ShowEmpDtlsFrm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShwEmpDtlsLbl.Text = "Employee Database Management";
            comboBox1.Text = "Click";
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public void DataGridChk()//Check if DataGrid is empty or not
        {
           if (dataGridView1.RowCount == 1)
            {
                dataGridView1.Visible = false;
                MessageBox.Show("The Given " + comboBox1.Text+ " is Invalid  \nEnter Valid " + comboBox1.Text);
            }
        }

        public void DbDataFetch(String Qry)//For Fetching data from database
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Qry, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "emp");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["emp"].DefaultView;
            DataGridChk();
        }

        public void SrchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (comboBox1.Text == "Employee ID" || comboBox1.Text == "Department ID" || comboBox1.Text == "Manager ID")
                {
                    if (textBox1.Text != "")
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        dataGridView1.Visible = true;
                        if (comboBox1.Text == "Employee ID")
                        {
                            string Qry = "select * from emp where emp_id='" + textBox1.Text + "' ";
                            DbDataFetch(Qry);
                        }
                        else if (comboBox1.Text == "Department ID")
                        {
                            string Qry = "select * from emp where  dep_id='" + textBox1.Text + "'  ";
                            DbDataFetch(Qry);
                        }
                        else if (comboBox1.Text == "Manager ID")
                        {
                            string Qry = "select * from emp where manager_id='" + textBox1.Text + "' ";
                            DbDataFetch(Qry);
                        }
                        con.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the ID...");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Choose Valid Option...");
                }
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException sqlException)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(sqlException.Message);
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EmpDtlsFrm edf = new EmpDtlsFrm();
            edf.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note, the `'" + textBox1.Text + "'` makes this susceptible to SQL injection, better to use sql parameters.